# Subtract two SUM GROUP BY fields

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sum

I have two tables `itemOrders` and `itemUsage`.

`itemOrders` has two fields: `item_number` and `qty_ordered`
`itemUsage` has two fields: `item_number` and `qty_used`

I'm trying to word my SQL query so that it sums up the quantity of each item number in both tables then subtracts the totals in `itemUsage` from `itemOrders`

I've come up with this so far:

```
SELECT itemOrders.item_number
    ,(
        SELECT sum(qty_ordered)
        FROM itemOrders
        GROUP BY itemOrders.item_number
        ) - (
        SELECT sum(qty_used)
        FROM itemUsage
        GROUP BY itemUsage.item_number
        ) AS item_total
FROM itemOrders
INNER JOIN itemUsage 
        ON itemOrders.item_number = itemUsage.item_number
GROUP BY itemOrders.item_number
```

What happens here is that all fields come out to 0.

Example if item number "A" was showing a total quantity of 3 ordered across all instances of "A" in the `itemOrders` table, and only a total quantity used of 1 across all instances of "A" in the `itemUsage` table. The sql should show the number one in the item_total field next to 1 instance of "A" in the item_number field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a `CARTESIAN PRODUCT` and repeting the values on the `SUM` just calculate each value separated and then `LEFT JOIN` both. In case no item are used `COALESCE` will convert `NULL` to `0`

```
SELECT io_total.item_number,  
       order_total - COALESCE(used_total, 0) as item_total
FROM (SELECT io.item_number,  sum(io.qty_ordered) as order_total
      FROM itemOrders io
      GROUP BY io.item_number
     ) io_total
LEFT JOIN (SELECT iu.item_number, sum(iu.qty_used) as used_total 
           FROM itemUsage iu
           GROUP BY iu.item_number
          ) as iutotal
        ON io_total.item_number = iutotal.item_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you are making three queries, two separate ones, one for each sum, and one with an inner join that isn't being used.
Try

```
Select itemOrders.item_number, sum(itemOrders.qty_ordered - itemUsage.qty_used) as item_total 
from itemOrders INNER JOIN itemUsage
On itemOrders.item_number = itemUsage.item_number
GROUP BY itemOrders.item_number
```